# Linking VS2010 with Assimp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assimp

I have been trying to get assimp working with VS2010. I have seen many questions similar to this but I just can't get it to work. Read the installation tutorials here http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/install.html and still can't get it to work.

This is what I did for VS2010 project setup:

1. All Configurations -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories ADDED
   C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\lib\assimp_release-dll_x64
2. All Configurations -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories ADDED
   C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\include
3. All Configurations -> Configuration Properties -> C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories ADDED
   C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\include
4. All Configurations -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies ADDED assimp.lib

When i write following code:

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>      // C++ importer interface
#include <assimp/scene.h>           // Output data structure
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>     // Post processing flags

Assimp::Importer importer;
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Assimp::Importer::Importer(void)" (??0Importer@Assimp@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'importer''(void)" (??__Eimporter@@YAXXZ)    C:\Users\Martin Liu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyGame\MyGame\Game.obj    MyGame

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Assimp::Importer::~Importer(void)" (??1Importer@Assimp@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'importer''(void)" (??__Fimporter@@YAXXZ) C:\Users\Martin Liu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyGame\MyGame\Game.obj    MyGame
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with that but... are you matching your app bitness (e.g. 32 bit) with the version of the libraries above (x64) ?

Comment: I think so, my comp is 64 bits and I used x64 versions do those libraries

Comment: okay, but is the visual studio project configured as 64? VS by default creates 32bit ones. You can check this out by right-clicking in your project and choosing "properties" and then "Configuration Manager" button

Comment: ah thank you, changing them from x64 to x86 solved my problems

Comment: Well, I'll make that an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your application's bitness matches your libraries' one. E.g. you can't link against x64 libraries if your project is 32 bit.

You can check this out by right-clicking in your project and choosing "*properties*" and then "*Configuration* Manager" button.